# How to return from a non-void function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, warnings, void

I have a function below that searches through a vector of `my_type`. Currently, it has a compilation warning: `control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`. It appears that as long as I am using a reference as my return type rather than a pointer, it is not possible to return a null-like value?

```
struct my_type{
    type_a a;
    type_b b;
}

    type_b& value(type_a& t){
        typename std::vector<my_type>::iterator it;  
        for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
            if ((*it).a == t) return (*it).b;
            }
    }
```

Comment: References can never be null.

Comment: Returning a reference to (a member of) an element in a container isn't a good idea anyway.

Comment: add ``return something_meaningfull`` when your ``for`` ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It appears that as long as I am using a reference as my return type rather than a pointer, it is not possible to return a null-like value?

Well, yes, but that's not the only issue.  References can never be `null`, but what happens if your `if` statement never evaluates to `true`?  You don't return *anything*.

Since references cannot be null, it is not valid to return `null`.  You must return a valid reference from all execution paths.

Also, your code is fragile at best.  You are returning a reference to a member of an element in a container... an element that may be moved at any point in the future, making said reference invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The question you have to think about is what should you return if 'nothing' is found when your function has to return `my_type`. How you handle this directly affects how the caller uses this function and assumptions made.

There are a few ideas you can think about. For example, if your `value` function returned a pointer type, you could just return `NULL` to indicate nothing. If it returned a string, you can use an empty string `""` or even a special string value like `"none"` to indicate that. For `type_b` you can create a special instance of it and just return that instance to indicate nothing. Other functions calling this would check the returned `type_b` against that instance to see if it's nothing. The point is, there are many ways to go about it and which way you choose is up to you.

But a better approach would be to use what's already provided by the stl -- in particular `std::find_if`. For example, you can create a functor which specifies when there's a match:

```
struct find_b
{
  const type_a &this_a;
  find_b(const type_a &a) : this_a(a) {}
  bool operator() (const my_type &lhs)
  {
    return lhs.a == this_a;
  }
};
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
item = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), find_b(t));
if(item == v.end()) { /* not found */ }
else { /* found, do something useful here */ }
```